# Custom pivot column names in many-to-many polymorphic relation?

Tags: laravel

Suppose we had

```
posts
    id - integer
    name - string

videos
    id - integer
    name - string

tags
    id - integer
    name - string

taggables
    custom_tag_id - integer
    custom_poly_id - integer
    custom_poly_type - string
```

How would I define the custom pivot table columns? From the documentation at https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_morphedByMany , this doesn't seem possible, since there doesn't appear to be a way to specify the polymorphic columns, specifically the `custom_poly_type`?

Comment: Its the `name` argument. e.g. `return $this->morphedByMany('App\YourModel', 'custom_poly');`

Comment: id and type are appended to the name, to derive full column name.

Comment: Ah I see. So basically, limited customization, no way to fully decouple the naming of the id and the type (not that it should be done, but if ever one ran into a strangely laid out legacy database, for example).

Comment: Correct. You could override the relevant methods from `HasRelationships` trait, if needed.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Was a matter of curiosity while going through the docs rather than any real need.